# highlighting items of recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I want to highlight the selected list item totally, not only background color but the whole list item should have same color.

This is the one without highlighting

[image: image 1]

I want the output as this was

[image: image 2]

I am getting just the background color. I have used this code

`view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);`

I am getting like this as output

[image: image 3]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/alert_Item"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

        android:background="@drawable/list_corners"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="8dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
         />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="108dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:text="member name"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/memberName"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="member name"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alertId"
            android:layout_width="132dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:text="alert id"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alertName"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/alertId"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="alert name"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: paste your possible xml code

Comment: put your xml layout for recyclerview item

Comment: In xml layout item...Add `android:duplicateParentState="true"` to the layout which does not show the background color and to the same layout you have to set the same selector of parent. What this does is, it will copy the parents state to the child.

Comment: Hi, If you could add your recyclerView implementation code i would tell you where to change

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit i have added xml code

Comment: you can set background of that relativeLayout to null when item selected, and back to `list_corners` when un-selected.

Comment: You need to set the color of cardview as well.

Comment: this `list_corners` made a problem you should change it to transparent when row selected